# highmaps/highcharts legend fixed in map

Tags: highcharts

I using highmaps / highcharts, but I need to see the legends of each part of the map fixed. Something like it looks like in the image below. My need is to display the legend without requiring the user to hover over

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcDTE.png)

Comment: I think that a best solution for your case will be using the SVGRenderer tool to render those custom labels and path do them. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path If you will get some troubles with that - please reproduce your attempt on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to check